# Admin redirect to admin site and user to user site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to authorize that if you are an admin, you will be redirected to an admin site. If you are a member, it will redirect you to the member site.

Here is my code on the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(Login model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (model.IsUserExist(model.EmailId, model.Password))
            {

                if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin"))
                {
                    ViewBag.UserName = model.EmailId; 
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(model.EmailId, false);

                    return RedirectToAction("AdminSite", "Home");
                }
                if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Member"))
                {
                    ViewBag.UserName = model.EmailId; 
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(model.EmailId, false); 
                    return RedirectToAction("MemberSite", "MobileHome"); 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Wrong Email or Password!");
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

I don't know what is wrong, but the site just stays on the login page. It just refreshes when I login as a member or admin. It didn't take me to the admin site or member site.

Comment: sorry it should be member to mobile site. and admin to the admin site. admins site is the one for desktop and the member is for mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use

```
RedirectFromLoginPage(
    string userName,
    bool createPersistentCookie
)
```

method you have to have ReturnURL variable name in the querystring. See the [specyfication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce.aspx=). So it don't get to `return RedirectToAction("MemberSite", "Home")` or `return RedirectToAction("AdminSite", "Home")`. If you will comment out that method it will redirect you to given action.